# Create a Java HashMap of HREF and linknames in java

Tags: java, url, hashmap, jsoup

So, I have a huuuge HTML file which has many such HREFs and link names

```
<A HREF="AccountCttR.html" TARGET="tableFrame">AccountCttRR</A><BR>
<A HREF="AccountCV.html" TARGET="tableFrame">AccCV</A><BR>
<A HREF="AccountCR.html#AccountHolder" TARGET="tableFrame">AccH</A><BR>
```

Now, I want to parse this HTML file, and create a Hash Map with

```
Key = <*.html>; value = <linkname>
```

Precondition: The HREFs are all unique. So, they can easily be used as keys for the hashmap. 
I know I can use JSoup, but how do I exactly do this (in java)? Please help?

Code used:
I'm trying to use this code:

```
// rawContent is the "string" output of bufferedreader

Element content = Jsoup.parse(rawContent).getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");

for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    String linkText = link.text();
    System.out.println(linkHref+" @@@ "+ linkText);
}
```

but it returns a Java `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Find the links. Pull out the URL and anchor tag text. Put in to map. What *specifically* is the issue?

Comment: "I know I can use JSoup" ... then, what's the question? Use that (or a different library that does what you need), or write your own HTML parser. I *highly* recommend the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It
>   provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data,
>   using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods

Here is a code you may try to store the links and details in a HashMap:

```
Document doc;
Map<String,String> hrefMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
try {

    // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

// get all links
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

             //put elements in the map
            hrefMap.put(link.attr("href"),link.text() );

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```